# Incorrect syntax near AND in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to fix the following query but I cannot see the mistake. Could you please point me what is wrong?

```
select *
from(
     SELECT a.fisrt_name,a.last_name,a.job_id
     FROM employees A
     WHERE A.salary >(Select avg(salary) from employees)) and a.salary < select (max(salary) from employees)
) b
where b.job_id=SY_ANA;
```

Comment: try this add a space after > in  A.salary >(Select avg(salary)

Comment: you need to add group by clause while using avg function

Comment: Your query with only brackets left - `((()))(()))` - that's not balanced.

Comment: `fisrt_name` - you probably want to fix that sooner rather than later

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: I see multiple potential problems.  You should explain what you want the query to do and provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

where clause condition string should be quoted

```
 select *
    from(
         SELECT a.fisrt_name,a.last_name,a.job_id
         FROM employees a
         WHERE a.salary >(Select avg(salary) from employees)
             and a.salary < (select max(salary) from employees)
    ) b
    where b.job_id='SY_ANA';
```

And i removed extra parenthesis

Answer (score 0):

You need to delete this little fella `)` right after `employees`

```
select *
from(
     SELECT a.fisrt_name,a.last_name,a.job_id
     FROM employees A
     WHERE A.salary >(Select avg(salary) from employees) and a.salary < select (max(salary) from employees)
) b
where b.job_id=SY_ANA;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select b.*
from(
     SELECT a.fisrt_name,a.last_name,a.job_id
     FROM employees A
     WHERE A.salary >(Select avg(salary) from employees) and a.salary < (select max(salary) from employees)
) b
where b.job_id="SY_ANA";
```

You are missing brackets in inner query and quotes in where condition

Comment: Don't force people to play "spot the difference". **Explain** and highlight what you've changed and why.

Answer (score 0):

```
    select *
from(
     SELECT a.fisrt_name,a.last_name,a.job_id
     FROM employees A
     WHERE A.salary >(Select avg(salary) from employees)) and a.salary < (select max(salary) from employees)
) b
where b.job_id='SY_ANA';
```

`(select max(salary) from employees)`  was  `select (max(salary) from employees)`
also missing qoutes in where